# Checkbox input array not recognized by PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have a form that has checkboxes like these:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='yourgame[]' value='soccer' /> Soccer<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='yourgame[]' value='tennis' /> Tennis<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='yourgame[]' value='basketball' /> Basketball<br>
```

In the php script, we get the values:

```
$yourgame = $_POST['yourgame'];
```

And there is validation:

```
if (empty($yourgame))
echo "Tick at least one Game.";
```

We keep getting the error message "Tick at least one Game." despite ticking several boxes. It seems the $yourgame[] array is not recognized.

I've also tried  `$yourgame = (array)$_POST['yourgame'];`  no success.

Comment: Could you please post your `<form>` tag?

Comment: The unchecked checkbox is not posted on the server side, so you need to add the condition if empty then no checkbox is not selected

Comment: Form tag is <form method="post" action="">

Comment: When the validation is removed, we get Warning : implode() [function.implode]: invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $checkedCandidates = 0;
    $values = $_POST['yourgame'];
    $checkedCandidates = count($values);

    if ($checkedCandidates < 1) {
        echo 'Tick at least one Game.';
    } else {
        echo 'Checked';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<form method="post">
<input type='checkbox' name='yourgame[]' value='soccer' /> Soccer<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='yourgame[]' value='tennis' /> Tennis<br> 
<input type='checkbox' name='yourgame[]' value='basketball' /> 
 Basketball<br>
<input type="submit" name="btnsave" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnsave'])){

$chk=isset($_POST['yourgame'])?$_POST['yourgame']:"";
if(!empty($chk)){

    print_r($chk);

}
else{

    echo 'Ops! select at least one value';
  }

  }
   ?>
```